# Does Godot have 3D Lights Textures/Cookies

Tags: textures, godot, light

I was wondering if there is a way to put a texture on a 3d Light. In unity it was called cookies.

This is an example of a cookie:

[image: This is an example of a cookie]

Comment: that is not a cookie ... it is an image ... cookies are text data that is exchanged between a server and a client

Comment: why are you asking here? ... godot has a forum

Comment: This feature was added to Godot 4.0. There you can set the `light_projector` property on `SpotLight3D` and set it to the texture you want. *Also, despite whatever Unity says, "cookie" is not a common name for this.* I can't figure out how the texture is being mapped, as I only see a small portion projected and that portion is projected with distortion.

Comment: Doing it in Godot 3.x takes more effort, as it would imply to add a shader on any material that is illuminated. I don't have the energy to look into it right now, but I have found a possible starting point here: https://godotengine.org/qa/28084/projected-texture - In general I'll advice against making very dark games in Godot 3.x, in particular relying heavily on spotlights, and that is because of the lack of normal bias, see: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/12028

Comment: This is the issue I ran into when I tried `light_projector` in Godot 4.0: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/50445

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my sample project:

https://github.com/tavurth/godot-simple-fps-camera

It works by setting two lights, one a little behind the other.
Then you use Sprite3D to mask the rear light and you can set the shadow color for the cookie and the world separately.